# In sharepoint 2016 Is it possible to await sharepoints Edit Form standard save request (the post that happens when you press save) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, form-post

What i want to do is have the user save the changes they have made to the list item in the edit form and then when the save is completed redirect them to another location instead of refresching the page which Sharepoint does standard.

I want the exact behavior of the edit form standard save button with all the field validation except the refresh that happens when the save is completed. Is it possible to do this with javascript?

Any other suggestions to tackle this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a different location after the user saves the item on the form by altering the 'Source=' querystring parameter.  Set it to the location you want to redirect people to after saving.